# Why the iViewUI `<Slider>` template do not show up in my project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The Slider do not show up (is blank).

I install the `iview` in `npm`:

```
npm install iview --save-dev
```

in the `main.js`:

```
import iView from 'iview'
Vue.use(iView)
```

In my `Reommend.vue` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Test01></Test01>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import Test01 from '../test/test01'

  export default{

    components: {
      Test01,
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

in my `test/test01.vue`:

```
<template>

  <div>
    <Slider v-model="value" range></Slider>
    123
  </div>

</template>

<script>

  export default{

    data(){
      return {
        value: [2, 22]
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

when I `npm run dev`, there do not shows the Slider, only shows the `123`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

If I comment the `Vue.use(iView)` in `main.js`, there will report Error:

```
vue.esm.js?efeb:578 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <Slider> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

So, why the `<Slider>` template do not show up in my project.

The official document is: https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/introduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Import the CSS](https://www.iviewui.com/docs/guide/start):

```
import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css';
```

So your `main.js` will have:

```
import iView from 'iview';
import 'iview/dist/styles/iview.css';
Vue.use(iView);
```

[**DEMO CODESANDBOX here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/6z0l3pkzwr).